# Menu ul style change on arrive to div

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have simple menu with uls inside it, and I would like to change the ul's style(with css) while the page arrive to a div(in content), I mean onscrolling and arriving to that div.
For example, I have this code:

css files

```
#menu {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width:100%;
}

.menutext {
    padding:25 40 30 !important;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menutext2 {
    padding:25 40 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
    color:red;
}

.alldivs {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:a9a9a9;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV1</div>
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV2</div>
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV3</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV1">DIV1</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV2">DIV2</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV3">DIV3</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
```

this is mycode http://jsfiddle.net/vu7Hh/

Shortly:
When I scroll and arrive to the to the top of DIV2 for example the second ul in the menu style change to .menustyle2(in different words it becomes red).
So I think I should use jQuery here to do that.

Comment: hmm... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802007/change-ul-style-when-arriving-to-divscrolling