# Change ul style when arriving to div(scrolling)

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I would like to change a ul style on scrolling and arrive to div using jQuery, explanation down.

CSS:

```
#menu {
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.menutext {
    padding:25 40 30 !important;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menutext2 {
    padding:25 40 0 !important;
    display:inline-block;
    color:red;
}

.alldivs {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:a9a9a9;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV1</div>
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV2</div>
    <div class="menutext">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV3</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV1">DIV1</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV2">DIV2</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div id="DIV3">DIV3</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
```

I want to change the div with the class "menutext" to class "menutext2" on scrolling and arriving to the top of the divs(first ul's class change from menutext1 to menutext2 on arriving to the div with the id DIV1, second ul's class change from menytext1 to menutext2 on arriving to the div with the id DIV2 AND the first ul's class return to menutext1 AS IT WAS and so on.

Comment: what's the question? what have you tried?

Comment: When I scroll and arrive to the to the top of DIV1 for example the first ul in the menu style change to .menustyle2(in different words it becomes red).

Comment: Where is `ul` element in your code? Also, did you try anything?

Comment: it's not ul it's div but it's same as ul(inside the menu).
yes I've tried this code but it doesnt work good:
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var mindist = 1000;
    var closest = '';
    $('.alldivs').each(function(i, el){
        var thisdist = Math.abs(scrolltop - $(el).offset().top);
        if (thisdist < mindist) {
            closest = el.id;
            mindist = thisdist;
        }
    });
    if (closest != '') {
        $('.menutext2').toggleClass('menutext menutext2');
        $('.'+closest).toggleClass('menutext menutext2');
    }
});

Comment: Should `#menu` be fixed positioned? How can you see change on it otherwise?

Comment: Yes it should be, and it is now.
Thank you for that, I forgot to set the position to fixed

Comment: ... what? Do you mean like scrollspy where you use js to modify DOM elements when an element reaches past a certain point when you scroll?

Comment: and you expect someone to write the code for you? or you actually have a question..

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/yckart/jquery.transe.js

Comment: Simply, I have a div and I want to change it's style on arriving to a div that related with it

Comment: @josh - valid point but in this case I wouldn't mind posting the code since I find scrollspy virtually useless for what I think he is asking for. The jquery to handle that is pretty short and easy so I wish someone had posted it when I was looking before I wasted hours trying to get scrollspy to do anything useful.

Comment: @ahmad - right but I am trying to understand what you mean by "arriving at" - do you mean when the user scrolls and that particular div reaches the top of the screen? I think that's what you're saying...

Comment: Yes ahmad, exactly, but NOTE THAT the div height isn't fixed, in some cases it takes 300px scrolling to arrive it in different cases it take less or more

Comment: Ok then this sounds like a case when scrollspy might do what you want out of the box. Have you looked into http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html

Comment: @AhmadTantori, why did you started two same questions?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801530/change-ul-style-when-arriving-to-div

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're asking, using only jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    var detectrange = 50; //how close to the top of the screen does it need to get
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop() + detectrange;
    $('.alldivs').each(function(i, el){
        if (scrolltop > $(el).offset().top) {
            $('.'+el.id).removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
        }
    });
});
```

Note that to make it work I had to apply the `alldivs` class on your `div1`, `div2`, `div3`, etc. and give the menu items classes corresponding to their IDs.

Demo in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ss7YF/

**EDIT** If you want only the closest one to be highlighted (for a fixed menu I'm guessing?) use this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e) {
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var mindist = 1000;
    var closest = '';
    $('.alldivs').each(function(i, el){
        var thisdist = Math.abs(scrolltop - $(el).offset().top);
        if (thisdist < mindist) {
            closest = el.id;
            mindist = thisdist;
        }
    });
    if (closest != '') {
        $('.menutext2').toggleClass('menutext menutext2');
        $('.'+closest).toggleClass('menutext menutext2');
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ss7YF/1/

Comment: It's kind a helpfull answer, I have just one problem before I can use it, I want the ul style to return to the FIRST style(menutext) on passing the div

Comment: You see where it says removeClass, and then where it says addClass? That's where the magic happens.

Comment: @AhmadTantori Well that's why I included the comment to explain the variable's purpose... but I've added an edited solution which might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YAHOOs YUI](http://yuilibrary.com) framework to write a javascript along the lines of something like this:

```
var Event = YAHOO.util.Event;

Event.on(window, 'scroll', function() {

    if (document.getElementById("DIV1").scrollTop == 0) {
        document.getElementById("DIV1").className = "menutext2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need jQuery, but I do not understand: You must apply menutext2 class when the scroll bars to see div1 or when you click div1?

set event (click or scroll and apply)

```
$('.menu').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/KrPSm/)

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 275) {
    $(".menutext").addClass(
        "menutext2");
} else {
    $(".menutext").removeClass(
        "menutext2");
}
```

});

I have this set to add `.menutext2` after you've scrolled down 275px, approximate top of div2, it shouldn't be hard to figure it out from here.

Comment: This is not what I need:( first of all I want the changes on ARRIVING to the div not after scrolling 275px, the div may be after 300px and may be after 50px, also the first div in menu for the first div in content, second div in menu for second div in content, third div in menu for the third div in content.

Comment: You may want to edit your question. If you need a precise answer you may need to ask your question more clearly.

Comment: I clearly said "I want to change the div with the class "menutext" to class "menutext2" **on scrolling and arriving to the top of the divs**"
Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, done it with jsFiddle 
[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/UL6tT/)

Replace .css with .addClass and .removeClass.
I use parent div of DIV1-3 because  you was style a height on it parent.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
var offsetDiv1 = $("#DIV1").offset().top;
var offsetDiv2 = $("#DIV2").offset().top;
var offsetDiv3 = $("#DIV3").offset().top;
if(top >= offsetDiv1 && top <= $("#DIV1").parent("div").height() + offsetDiv1){
   // alert(top);
     $("#menu").css("background", "black");   
}else if(top >= offsetDiv2 && top <= $("#DIV2").parent("div").height() + offsetDiv2){
   // alert(top);
     $("#menu").css("background", "blue");  
}else if(top >= offsetDiv3 && top <= $("#DIV3").parent("div").height() + offsetDiv3){
    //alert(top);
     $("#menu").css("background", "yellow");  
}else{
      $("#menu").css("background", "gray");    
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want same as what i implemented on my page.

Have look on menu section on http://s-yadav.github.com/contextMenu.html

As per your requirement try this.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menutext" linkId="DIV1">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV1</div>
    <div class="menutext"  linkId="DIV2">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV2</div>
    <div class="menutext"  linkId="DIV3">Change the style of me to .mebutext2 on arriving to DIV3</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="alldivs"><div class="contentDiv" id="DIV1">DIV1</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div class="contentDiv" id="DIV2">DIV2</div></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="alldivs"><div class="contentDiv" id="DIV3">DIV3</div></div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

    var menu=$('#menu'),
        menuText=menu.find('.menuText'),
        DIV1=$('#DIV1'),
        DIV2=$('#DIV2'),
        DIV3=$('#DIV3'),
        DIV1Top=DIV1.offset().top,
        DIV2Top=DIV2.offset().top,
        DIV3Top=DIV3.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var win=$(this),
        scrollTop=$(this).scrollTop();


    //to make nav menu selected according to scroll
    var start=scrollTop;
    menuText.filter('.menutext2').removeClass('menutext2').addClass('menutext');
    if(start>DIV3Top){
        menuText.filter('[linkId="DIV3"]').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
        }
    else if (start>DIV2Top){
        menuText.filter('[linkId="DIV2"]').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
        }
    else if(start>DIV1Top){
        menuText.filter('[linkId="DIV1"]').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
        }   
});
});
```

Update:

Generic method.

```
$(function () {

    var menu = $('#menu'),
        menuText = menu.find('.menuText'),
        contentDiv = $('.contentDiv');

    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        var win = $(this),
            scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();


        //to make nav menu selected according to scroll
        var start = scrollTop;
        menuText.filter('.menutext2').removeClass('menutext2').addClass('menutext');
        for (var i = 0; i < contentDiv.length; i++) {
            var elm = $(contentDiv[i]),
                id = contentDiv[i].id,
                top = elm.offset().top,
                nextTop = elm.next().offset().top || 1000000000;
            if (start > top && start < nextTop) {
                menuText.filter('[linkId="' + id + '"]').removeClass('menutext').addClass('menutext2');
                break;
            }
        }

    });
```

The second method is shorter and generic but less efficient than first one as every time loop will go inside scroll event. and scroll event are executed very frequently.

If the number of '.contentDiv' is less, i will prefer to follow first approach else follow second approach.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I need, works perfect THANK YOU:) but I wanted to ask you if you can make it with less codes, I mean I know codes with jQuery that takes ANY div of the three divs and remove its class and replace the new class without making a code for every div I want(one code for all the divs that take the div's id and replace the class of every div with another class in one code for all)
If you have any idea how to do that please tell me, thank you very much anyway.

Comment: I really don't know why it doesn't work :( can you PLEASE try to use that code with my codes and try to change some elements to get it work? I think this code will work with some edits, I tried to change the code elements and worked with it but unfortunately I'm not that good with jQuery, if you need you can use this website(http://jsfiddle.net/) to enter all the codes together and run it, then you can give it to me, Anyway thank you very much for your efforts, if you wasn't able to do it thank you very much anyway for the first code.

Comment: have you added contentDiv class on you div1 div2 div3 ??

Comment: Oouch . in if condindition i had misplaced menuText2 and menutext1.. Just try the new update..